# Changing price format from RON30.00 to 30.00 RON

Tags: magento2, price

I'm trying to achieve this change. I've searched everywhere and found nothing. Is it possible to reorder the pricing format ?

Comment: Have you tried modifying the Block yielding the price?

Comment: Have you multi store or only one store?

Answer (score 4):

We should use event `currency_display_options_forming`:

*app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="currency_display_options_forming">
        <observer name="localize_currencysymbol_currency_display_options" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\ModifyCurrencyOptions" />
    </event>
</config>
```

*app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/ModifyCurrencyOptions.php*

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Locale\Currency;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ModifyCurrencyOptions implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\CurrencySymbol\Model\System\CurrencysymbolFactory
     */
    protected $symbolFactory;

    const RIGHT = 16;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\CurrencySymbol\Model\System\CurrencysymbolFactory $symbolFactory
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\CurrencySymbol\Model\System\CurrencysymbolFactory $symbolFactory)
    {
        $this->symbolFactory = $symbolFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Generate options for currency displaying with custom currency symbol
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $baseCode = $observer->getEvent()->getBaseCode();
        $currencyOptions = $observer->getEvent()->getCurrencyOptions();
        $originalOptions = $currencyOptions->getData();
        $currencyOptions->setData($this->getCurrencyOptions($baseCode, $originalOptions));

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get currency display options
     *
     * @param string $baseCode
     * @param array $originalOptions
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getCurrencyOptions($baseCode, $originalOptions)
    {
        $currencyOptions = [];

        if ($baseCode == 'RON') {

            $currencyOptions['position'] = self::RIGHT; // switch currency symbol position to the RIGHT
        }

        return array_merge($originalOptions, $currencyOptions);
    }
}
```

Take a look at **vendor/magento/module-currency-symbol** and a good sample module [here](https://github.com/Magento-Japan/m2-jplocalize).

Comment: How to add one space between price and symbol? is there any chance?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go from your root folder to vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml
2. Find the language file. In my case en.xml
3. Look for `<currencyFormat>`

A line just below you will find the `<pattern>`

Change the side of the weird symbol and leave it like this:

Before

```
<currencyformatlength>
   <currencyformat>
      <pattern>¤ #,##0.00</pattern>
   </currencyformat>
</currencyformatlength>
```

After

```
<currencyformatlength>
   <currencyformat>
       <pattern>#,##0.00 ¤</pattern>
   </currencyformat>
</currencyformatlength>
```

Comment: How to override this file are you know?

Comment: Its also coming in magento2 but how to override are you know, vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data